# Responsive images using innerfade plugin

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, responsive

I have setup a responsive design. Now I am using the innerfade plugin. It carosels through the pictures as it should, but I notice that when the width of the page changes the height of the picture grows smaller and does not cover the entire area needed.So by the time it shrinks from a width of 1440px to 320px the img height is bairly 25 percent on the original div. I have a css element targeting img {width:%; height:auto;}. The containerheight in the jQuery is set to '100%'. I tried 'auto' within JQuery counterheight as well as to the containerheight to a static '400px'. What can I do to have the image cover the entire div while using innerfade? If it was a regular image I wouldn't have this issue, but this is my first time with this plugin. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Update the CSS & HTML here with jsfiddle or codesnippet

Comment: That's supposed to say img{ width:100%; height:auto;}

Comment: Will add code when I get back to work in the morning. Literally in bed on my cell phone trying to figure this out.

Comment: Ok so I had a co-worker come and save my backside. Here is the code below for those of you desperately searching the internet as I was.

Answer (score 0):

[Change #test li to whatever id your order list is named. Change 'wrapper' to the name of the div the pictures are going in. This does work. I just dont know how to add images on here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxkHa.png)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#test').innerfade();

   $(window).on('load', function(){
   var sample = $('#test li').height() + 5;
    $('.wrapper').css({'height': sample});
   });
   
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
    var sample = $('#test li').height() + 5;
    $('.wrapper').css({'height': sample}); 

   });

  });
 </script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
  .wrapper {
   position: relative;
  }
  #test img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
  }

  #test li {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: block;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 100%;
  }
  
  .clear {
   clear: both;
  }
 </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>test</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.innerfade.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#test').innerfade();

   $(window).on('load', function(){
   var sample = $('#test li').height() + 5;
    $('.wrapper').css({'height': sample});
   });
   
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
    var sample = $('#test li').height() + 5;
    $('.wrapper').css({'height': sample}); 

   });

  });
 </script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper" style="width: 100%; max-width: 700px; margin: 30px auto; background-color: #666; height: 500px;">
   
   <ul id="test" style="margin: 5% auto; padding: 0; list-style: none;">
    <li><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/img2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/img3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/img4.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/img5.jpg" alt=""></li>
   </ul>


 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="wrapper" style="width: 100%; max-width: 700px; margin: 30px auto;">
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris elit est, rutrum quis commodo sed, pharetra id erat. Pellentesque vel suscipit velit. Nulla nec ante hendrerit, sagittis neque id, ultricies urna. Etiam luctus nisl ac cursus cursus. In nec viverra ligula. Nullam porta tellus sit amet convallis pharetra. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean suscipit pretium mi in luctus. Phasellus vestibulum sem dictum, porta quam convallis, sollicitudin augue. Quisque elit metus, tristique vel maximus a, congue at mi. Duis pharetra, massa vel maximus consequat, ex ipsum faucibus augue, ultricies eleifend nisi velit vel ex.
  </p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet accumsan justo. Maecenas eget luctus magna, in dictum ex. Mauris posuere risus et magna aliquet dignissim. Sed non condimentum enim. Sed gravida tincidunt arcu, id cursus velit. Donec sit amet consequat dolor.
  </p>
  
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Change #test li to whatever id your order list is named. Change 'wrapper' to the name of the div the pictures are going in. This does work. I just dont know how to add images on here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf1u1.png)